# Remote Desktop assistance

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-control, remote-access, remote-connection, remote-assistance

Here is my current scenario:

- I have two PCs at different locations connected to same ISP.    *Note on both sides same configuration software / hardware*
- ISP has provided me a device which is connected to my ordinary land-line.
- Device is connected to my PC through LAN card RJ-45 connector(Ethernet).
- Device assigns IP address through built-in DHCP. *example 1st location PC 192.168.1.2, 2nd location PC 192.168.1.3*
- I have 1MB shared-broadband connection.
- On both sides OS is Windows-XP.
- Device IP is 192.168.1.1 .

**Question:**  I need to connect both computers so that File-sharing, Print-sharing, Remote Desktop, Live audio/Video conference and other related services could be used.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are both computers on the same network, or are they in like two different houses?

Comment: Different locations remote from each other but using same ISP.

Most-likely both computers are connected to MAN or VPN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do (most of) this, you simply need to enable SMB/port 137 from the router to each pc.

However, I really would not recommend this at all. Nearly all remote hacks or attacks against Windows take advantage of machines that have file sharing on and are directly connected to the internet. You can look at technologies such as [IPSec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec), but for a small environment, it will most likely be too much trouble to implement.

Audio/Video conferencing should work over the internet without problem (but it depends on the program).

File sharing can be accomplished with [Mesh](http://www.mesh.com) or [DropBox](http://www.getdropbox.com).

Print sharing - I do not have a good solution for this.

Remote desktop will work over the internet if you forward port 3389 from your router to each machine... And you can actually print remotely over Remote Desktop if you share the printer, so this may be a solution.

You may also want to take a look at VPN technology such as [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/). Then it will be as if the machines are on the same network.

Comment: I also say Hamachi, which would have been my answer, as the easiest and most secure solution.

Comment: Another option would be something like http://logmein.com which allows remote control/desktop sharing (and, in the paid version, file sharing).

Comment: @Wil is correct in saying that the correct solution to this is to use a VPN.

Comment: Hamachi is exactly what I thought of when reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try [TurboMeeting](http://www.rhubcom.com), you can do remote access plus it has the functions you are looking for. (file sharing, remote printing & conferencing)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Logmein.co](http://www.logmein.com)m. They have a PRO option that enabled all your wish list.

Hamachi did the job but my connection was so slow, I was not able to do it with satisfactory result.

Answer (score 0):

[TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com/) offers free version for non-commercial use. And all the requirements mentioned here viz. File-sharing, Print-sharing, Remote Desktop, Live audio/Video conference can be carried out in it. You can even record the screencast of a remote session.
However, the file sharing in Teamviewer is a one way and one time manual process. Use a shared folder on Dropbox if changes in future are anticipated on the file and you want both copies (on PC#1 and on PC#2) remain synced.